# WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13___default(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Context : I am building a small library (let's call it myLibrary here) using TypeScript and Webpack. I built it, imported it in a react application but the react application crash.

**Library side**

My main entry point (index.ts) has a default export as such :

```
import wrapper from "./wrapper";

export default wrapper;
```

And my wrapper file exposes a default export which is a function (wrapper.ts) :

```
const create = () => {
  // Some functions
  return {
    init,
    close,
    getBase,
    setBase
  }
}
export default create;
```

The library pass all the unit tests easily.

**React application side**

After building and when importing my library in a React application, I have no Typescript error but my React app crashes with the following message :

```
TypeError: myLibrary__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13___default(...) is not a function
```

After calling my library like that :

```
import createAPI from "myLibrary";
const api = createAPI(); // Crash here even though I should have a nice object containing my functions
```

It's really strange as TS really compiled nicely to JS without any warnings.

My library wepback config (4.43.0) which I use to build with command `webpack --config webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
    ]
  }
}
```

My library TS config (3.7.3) :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT :
After updating default export to named export :

```
import { createAPI } from "myLibrary";
const api = createAPI();
```

I got a new error

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

And when I try to `console.log(typeof createAPI);` I got an undefined, which should not be possible as my tests are passing and TS doesn't complain.

Comment: What is your `myLibrary` anyway? Does it export a default function as well?

Comment: `myLibrary` is the library I built with webpack :)

Comment: Instead of default exports, what happens if you use named exports instead? IMO default exports suck anyway. See https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/defaultisbad

Comment: I'm quite unsure to get your context correctly. Did you mean you built a simple library which export the wrapper as default then use it in a different project? The issue is happening in the current that project. Is that correct? And what project do above webpack.config & tsconfig belong to anyway?

Comment: I just updated my question :)

Comment: If you can provide the build file of your library, it would be great since I'm keen to check which module that is built

Comment: You can get the module at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@upandgo/scorm-wrapper

Comment: I've just tried for you but it seems you didn't export anything at all so you might have to check the way you export things & how to build your library such as which module type do you target to (cjs/esm/umd/...)? since webpack just supports a number of module types.

Comment: By the way your code has been built with production mode so I couldn't help you to find anything helpful though

Comment: If I didn't export anything my tests (which use my library main entry point) should not run AND Typescript should actually let me know when I import my library on another project that I have an undefined whereas the autocomplete and type inference work great :/
I'll investigate further as it was working when I didn't use Webpack

Comment: Hold on. I found something interesting. It looks like you bundle your library with webpack which means you might have to set some library props as following snippet. I'll comment them as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your webpack config of the library to point out library name & its module type:

```js
output: {
  path: './dist',
  filename: 'index.js',
  library: 'scorm-wrapper',
  libraryTarget: 'umd'
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked with named export and I'm happy with that :)

Comment: I have tried the same solution but not working for me...getting TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Answer (score 0):

If you updated webpack to version 5.x.x, then the issue might be related to [output.library setting issue](https://hinty.io/devforth/fix-webpack-imported-module-is-not-a-function-for-webpack5/)

so if you have library setting in webpack output try to remove it:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  filename: 'painterro.commonjs2.js',
  library: 'Painterro',  // ⏪ this is the issue
  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
 },
```

Read more in issue [Fix _*webpack_imported_module* is not a function for webpack5](https://hinty.io/devforth/fix-webpack-imported-module-is-not-a-function-for-webpack5/)